# Having trouble to initialize google-cloud-platform, gcloud failed to load

Tags: macos, google-cloud-platform

Computer System : macOS Mojave, 10.14.4
when running gcloud init, it generate error

```
           ERROR: gcloud failed to load: Error when calling the                metaclass bases
           Cannot create a consistent method resolution
           order (MRO) for bases ordereddict, MutableMapping, CommentedBase
           gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
           import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
           from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
           from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display
           from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer
           from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import yaml_printer
           from googlecloudsdk.core.yaml import dict_like
           from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml_location_value
           from ruamel import yaml
           from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
           from ruamel.yaml.loader import BaseLoader, SafeLoader, Loader, RoundTripLoader  # NOQA
           from ruamel.yaml.constructor import (
           from ruamel.yaml.comments import *                               # NOQA
           class CommentedMap(MutableMapping, ordereddict, CommentedBase):
           cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
           Cannot create a consistent method resolution

           This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

           Please verify that the following is the path to a   working Python 2.7 executable:
           /Users/IDK/.pyenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/python

           If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.

           If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall                the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
           https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

The directory of python interpreter are computed by
        import sys

```
    print(sys.executable)
```

and

```
    Python -V
```

Return

```
    Python 2.7
```

not sure if there is anything else i should mention?

by running

```
    pip freeze
```

i get

```
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January  1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
```

however i need python 2.7 to support gcp....

Someother updates here,

when running command,

```
    ./install.sh

    Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/IDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py",                 line 12, in <module>
        import bootstrapping
      File "/Users/IDK/google-cloud-        sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 44, in <module>
        from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
      File "/Users/IDK/google-cloud-        sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 36, in <module>
        from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import creds
      File "/Users/IDK/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/creds.py", line 40, in <module>
        import sqlite3
      File         "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2        .7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from dbapi2 import *
      File         "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
        from _sqlite3 import *
    ImportError:         dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Vers        ions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Symbol not found:         _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.        7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
     in         /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.        7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

Comment: Run `pip freeze` and include the output in your question. Your error typically means that another Python library/package is interfering with gcloud. This line `from ruamel import yaml` is suspect. If you figure out which one, please post an answer.

Comment: i had updated the output of pip freeze

Comment: Your Python and/or Pip installation is broken. Reinstall. I would delete first so that you have a clean install. Then for each project, I would use virtualenv after reinstalling. This will allow you to install Python 2.x and 3.x and select the installation with virtualenv. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: i have python managed with pyenv,  are you suggesting me to uninstall everything and re-install them with virtualenv?

Comment: No, you install virtualenv after you have Python, Pip and gcloud installed and working correctly. You could install Python 2.x to a new directory and then change your path to verify that that fixes gcloud and leave your current installation as is. You would then just switch your path / environment between the two setups. This is a bandaid to help diagnose what is wrong.

Comment: i have somemore updates above, can you please take a look?

Comment: Your system is messed up. My only advice for you is to remove Python, etc. Reboot and then install fresh.

Comment: If i were to remove pip, shall i remove every packeges that is installed with pip?

Comment: My only advice for you is to remove Python, etc. Reboot and then install fresh.

Comment: I'm interested to know if this issue is solved, if so, I would like  to know how it was fixed.

Thanks!